# Mysql error when running from command prompt in admin mode

Tags: mysql, windows, environment-variables, system

How to resolve this error when I am trying to run mysql from command line? I have added mysql to my windos system variable path and am not getting how to fix this problem. Below is the error which I am getting

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld"
>
> 2021-03-04T05:35:10.555512Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 12472
>
> 2021-03-04T05:35:10.558422Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
>
> 2021-03-04T05:35:10.558502Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
>
> 2021-03-04T05:35:10.558647Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
>
> 2021-03-04T05:35:10.574311Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>
> 2021-03-04T05:35:10.574526Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Location of mysql:   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin

[System variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLJ9U.png)

Comment: *'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)* Check that: 1) This directory exists 2) Current OS account have full access nask to this directory (by default user account have RO in Program Files).

Comment: @Akina There is no such folder as "data" in the MySql directory folder. Should i reinstall mysql for this? What should i do for this?

Comment: Firstly - simply try to create it.

Comment: Yeah, done. But it dosn't show any error instead the shell didn't open. The error log is the data directory has this :

Comment: 2021-03-04T07:02:15.107432Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 13876
2021-03-04T07:02:15.558344Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2021-03-04T07:02:15.563827Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-03-04T07:02:15.564759Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-03-04T07:02:15.566393Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Comment: *But it dosn't show any error instead the shell didn't open.* MySQLD is **NOT** a shell !

Comment: @Akina  Pardon me. Im kinda new to this sql stuff and all.